# data from http-mock not showing in template

Tags: templates, ember.js, ember-cli

I set up an http-mock like so on the get http verb

```
usersRouter.get('/:pin', function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        "users": {
            "id": 1234,
            "pin": 1234,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "phone": 8436376960
        }
    });
});
```

my route is looking up this information like so with a pin number passed as a param from a form input on a previous page

```
model: function(params) {
    this.store.find('user', params.pin);
}
```

my template is simply trying to display them like so

```
<span class="name">{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</span>
<span class="email">{{email}}</span>
```

Also my model for reference

```
pin: DS.attr('number'),
first_name: DS.attr('string'),
last_name: DS.attr('string'),
email: DS.attr('string'),
phone: DS.attr('number')
```

I'm not getting an error in the console but there is nothing displayed on the page, in the ember inspector in the data tab I see my data correctly being passed to the route

Is there some piece I'm missing here? This is my first ember-cli app.

UPDATE:

Based on Buck Doyle's answer I updated the express code like so

```
usersRouter.get('/:pin', function(req, res) {
    var user = USERS.filter(function(el) {
      return el.pin == req.params.pin;
    });

    res.send({"users": [user]});
});
```

Which pulls from an array defined outside of the .get like so

```
var USERS = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "pin": 1234,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "email@example.com",
  "phone": 8436376960
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "pin": 5678,
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "email": "email@example.org",
  "phone": 8436375738
}
];
```

I now get an assertion error

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: Expected an object as `data` in a call to `push`/`update` for user , but was [object Object]
```

And the ember inspector no longer shows my data being returned at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users` should return an array, not an object:

```
"users": [{
  "id": 1234,
  "pin": 1234,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "email@example.com",
  "phone": 8436376960
}]
```

But if [this example](https://github.com/cball/ember-cli-http-mocks-example/blob/master/server/mocks/band.js) is correct, you’ll need filtering in your `usersRouter`. If you save the above as USERS:

```
usersRouter.get('/:pin', function(req, res) {
  var pin = req.params.pin;
  var user = USERS.filter(function(user) {
    return user.pin.toString() == pin;
  })[0];
  res.send({"users": user});
});
```

I was able to verify the above by running your test application and accessing the store directly, since I don’t understand how your interface is supposed to work.

```
store = WmiCheckIn.__container__.lookup('store:main');
jane = store.find('user', '5678')
console.log(jane.get('first_name')); // -> Jane
```

Comment: There must be something else happening here, I'm still getting these errors. I posted my working code up on github for reference. I have tried applying your updates but with no luck.
https://github.com/Jordan4jc/ember-check-in

Comment: I was able to get rid of the assertion error, and run your console commands and got the same output, but the content still wouldn't display in the template. I noticed I was not returning the store.find, added return before the store.find finally put it in my template. Thanks for your help!